# sql server property "maximum server memory" disabled

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to set the maximum server memory option for a SQL server, but this option is disabled for me.
i have logged in through windows authentication, and logged into windows with the administrator user.

you can find this option by right click on DB server -> Select Properties -> Memory tab.

Please see the screenshot of the properties screen in the link 
[image]

Please let me know how can i change the memory option and why is it disabled for me. am i missing some permission?

Answer (score 1):

Try:
  USE master
  EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1'

then stop and restart the server.

Comment: hi Danny,

thanks for a quick response. this database server is on production  and on client site. it will be hard to restart the server at this moment. i will try this option and get back to you soon.

Thanks
Nikhil